# Please explain what this jquery selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

```
$(this).parent().find('> ul')
```

What is this selecting, I don't really understand what the jquery API is saying on the find() function.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It moves from the targeted element (`$(this)`) to the parent, and then selects all `ul` elements that are immediate children (not just descendants) of that parent element. Effectively, then, it just selects sibling elements of the current element, and is equivalent to:

```
$(this).siblings('ul');
```

Incidentally, the jQuery API is awesome for reading about jQuery methods. To find information about something use the URL `http://api.jquery.com/` and then append the method that you want to find out about.

So, if you want to read about `siblings()`, the URL becomes: [`http://api.jquery.com/siblings/`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

References:

- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Answer (score 3):

this = this element. It would be in context of the where you are in the DOM.

this.parent() traverses the DOM on (this) to it's containing (parent) element.

.find() looks into that containing(parent) element and  only selects direct children of ul using that css selector ('> ul')

.find() traverses the DOM based on parameters given.